# Oracle 11g: SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux, oracle-sql-developer, redhat

How would I use the pre-installed SQLDeveloper that comes packaged within Oracle 11g if I am invoking it with a user that has no oracle or admin rights on linux?

[image]

Would it be enough just to change permissions to the sqldeveloper folder, just as shown below:

```
chmod -R a+x sqldeloper/
```

Or it would be better to install SQLdeveloper with the "user" that has not oracle or admim rights?

Comment: Right now you are showing the sqldeveloper directory. Inside it is the actual executable wrapper script (sqldeveloper.sh) that has the right permissions. So you can actually execute `$ORACLE_HOME/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh` on the server. I would see it as a last resort as the version is really dated. And replacing this directory with the newest version is not something I would do. So, yes, you can use the bundled sqldeveloper, but you are better off not running it from the server but from your client with a new version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not touch that directory, I have not found any references of other users using the SQL Developer software that comes with database binaries. Additionally, SQL Developer shipped with the database binaries is kind of outdated. Even 12.1.0.2 comes with SQL Developer 3.2

I would just perform a seperate install.

Also, I find it unusual that someone, who is not the DBA, wants to run SQL Developer on the database server itself. Why not just install it on the client side?

(To be honest, I would not even include SQL Developer in the database binaries package and install process, but it can not be customized.)

Comment: Basically, I am installing Oracle/SQL Developer on a local machine for development purposes alongside with all the development tools, So, I was wondering if was able to run the pre-installed SQL Developer with my user for development. Thanks.

Comment: get the latest version from OTN, the version that ships with Oracle 11g is ANCIENT.